# How do you remove tap gesture recognizer from the scene dock?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to ios development and am following this tutorial: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/WorkWithViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1

I have an out of date `tap gesture recognizer` on the scene dock like here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Art/WWVC_scenedock_2x.png

and I would like to remove it. But for some reason google turns up absolute no answers on how to remove it. Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the `viewController`. Then in `Document Outline`, select the gesture recogniser and press delete

[image: Screenshot]